# parseInt() unexpectedly equating to NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a textbox that may be blank or numeric (non-numeric characters are validated at a prior juncture).

When I use intParse(), my integer outputs as NaN.

## My Code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" value=""/>
<button>Input number or leave blank to test</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('button').click(function() {

    //Check normal value...
    var $textboxvalue = $('#textbox').val();
    alert("#textbox=" + $textboxvalue);

    //If no value, set as 0 to avoid Nan for intParse...
    var $textbox;               
    if ($('#textbox').val()) {
        $textbox = $('#textbox').val();
    }
    else{
        $textbox = 0;
    }   
    alert("$textbox=" + $textbox);

    //Parse integer...
    var $textboxParsed = parseInt($($textbox).val(), 10);
    alert("$textboxParsed=" + $textboxParsed);

    //Subsequent action...
    var $textboxPlus5 = $textboxParsed + 5;
    alert("$textboxPlus5=" + $textboxPlus5);

});
```

**JSFIDDLE:**
https://jsfiddle.net/f4n6rz1p/1/

Why is intParse() producing NaN and am I correct to conditionally change blank inputs to zero to avoid Nan for intParse()?

Comment: Do you have an element with **tag name** `0`, i.e. `<0 />`? I don't think so. I think you want `parseInt($textbox, 10);`.

Comment: Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/f4n6rz1p/2/

Comment: Why do all your variables start with `$`? It's annoying.

Comment: $ variables are confusing folks with jquery objects...

Comment: @FelixKling You provided the correct answer first. If you'd like to repurpose your comment as an answer, I'll select it.

Comment: @RobertRozas Thanks for the JSFIDDLE demo.

Comment: @LyeFish Not my intention. Apologies. I thought it was an interchangeable practice for jQuery variables. I prefer it because it's akin to PHP variables though I can understand how it's visually confusing in jQuery.

Comment: @kmcnamee Acknowledged. Thanks.

Comment: @ClarusDignus: Just FYI, in JavaScript code using jQuery, a variable name starting with `$` usually means "this variable refers to a jQuery object", e.g. `var $spans = $("span");`. Hence the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code, you're setting `$textbox` to the **value** of the text box (or 0):

```
var $textbox;               
if ($('#textbox').val()) {
    $textbox = $('#textbox').val();
}
else{
    $textbox = 0;
}
```

And then you have an extra `$(...).val()` where you're parsing:

```
var $textboxParsed = parseInt($($textbox).val(), 10);
// Here ----------------------^^--------^^^^^^^
```

At that point, since `$textbox` has the **value** from the text box in it, that means you're asking jQuery to create a jQuery object based on that value. That jQuery object will presumably have no elements in it, as searching for (say) `$("123")` won't find anything. So when you call `val` on it, you get `undefined`, because `val` on an empty jQuery set gives you `undefined`. Then `parseInt` then converts that `undefined` to the string `"undefined"` before trying to parse it — and then gives you `NaN`.

You don't want either the `$(...)` or the second `.val` call:

```
var $textboxParsed = parseInt($textbox, 10);
```

---

Side note: If you want to use `0` for an empty text box, you can use [JavaScript's curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) to make that a bit more concise:

```
var $textbox = $('#textbox').val() || 0;
```

`$textbox` will end up with the value from the textbox if it's not blank, or `0` if it is blank.

(Or use `"0"` because you're going to parse it later, but calling `parseInt` on something that's already a number is harmless.)

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion using the or operator has neatly streamlined my code.

Answer (score 4):

I think it should be:

```
var $textboxParsed = parseInt($textbox , 10);
```

Instead of:

```
var $textboxParsed = parseInt($($textbox).val(), 10);
```

**Edit**: I added rational for why the above should be done in a comment.  Thinking further, you may be able to simplify your code:

```
var $textboxvalue = $('#textbox').val();
$textbox = '' === $textboxvalue ? 0 : parseInt($textboxvalue);
```

This is assuming your input value is either blank (i.e. an empty string, without whitespace) or a numeric integer value.

Comment: Why should be that way??

Comment: $textbox already has the value you want to parse.  Although, in the case where you set it to `0` (a Number type), the `parseInt` call isn't really necessary, as it returns the same value of `0`.  In the other case, where $textbox is a String, then parseInt is converting it to a Number type.